# Inject multiple ServiceBusClient in ASP.net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, azure-web-app-service

I want to inject multiple ServiceBusClient with same connectionstring but different queue name.

```cs
    _services.TryAddSingleton(implementationFactory =>
    {
        var serviceBusConfiguration = implementationFactory.GetRequiredService<Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<UserEventConsumerSetting>>().Value;
    
        var serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(serviceBusConfiguration.ServiceBusConnectionString, new ServiceBusClientOptions
        {
            TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets
        });
    
        return serviceBusClient.CreateReceiver(serviceBusConfiguration.ServiceBusQueueName, new ServiceBusReceiverOptions
        {
            ReceiveMode = ServiceBusReceiveMode.PeekLock
        });
    });
```

In order to use I have to create ServiceBusSender Instance.

```cs
    private readonly ServiceBusSender _serviceBusSender;
    
    public CarReservationMessagingService(ServiceBusSender serviceBusSender)
    {
        _serviceBusSender = serviceBusSender ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceBusSender));
    }
    
    public async Task PublishNewCarReservationMessageAsync(CarReservation carReservation)
    {
        var carReservationIntegrationMessage = new CarReservationIntegrationMessage
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            CarId = carReservation.CarId,
            CustomerId = carReservation.CustomerId,
            RentFrom = carReservation.RentFrom,
            RentTo = carReservation.RentTo
        };
    
        var serializedMessage = JsonSerializer.Serialize(carReservationIntegrationMessage);
        ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage(serializedMessage);
        await _serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(message);
    }
```

How can I inject multiple servicebusclient and use them differently?

Comment: for the article https://daniel-krzyczkowski.github.io/Cars-Island-ASP-NET-Core-API-Integration-With-Azure-Service-Bus-Queue/

Comment: The examples are a bit confusing. What are you trying to do exactly? On the first part of your example you're injecting a receiver but on the second example, you're creating a sender

Comment: @ArcaArtem basically ServiceBusClient takes the connection string and CreateReceiver take the name of the queue and you can use it by calling ServiceBusReceiver.
I want to register more then one receiver for the same servicebusclient because I have 2 queues.

Comment: Ok could you consider reflecting that in your second part of the example as to prevent further confusion? On the first part of your example, you're injecting a `ServiceBusReceiver` but on the second part, you're depending on the `ServiceBusSender`, which are two different classes. The same approach for using multiple queues can be applied to both cases so doesn't really matter which is which but making them consistent would make the question read better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, In other IoC containers (like Unity) there is posibility to specify named dependencies. You specify name when regster something like this:

```
container.RegisterSingleto<SomeClassImplementation>("Name")
```

and then in class where you use is it you  should specify attribute with this name

```
[DependencyAttribute("Name")]
```

But there are no such function in .net core.
You can use Unity.
Or you can make some imitation of this functionality.

Let's create enum (or constants if you want)

```
enum ServiceBusQueue { ServiceBus1, ServiceBus2, ServiceBus3}
```

Then create service buc provider

```
public class ServiceBusQueueProvider
{
    private Dictionary<ServiceBusQueue, ServiceBusSender > _senders;

    public ServiceBusQueueProvider()
    {
        //Method to initialize all queues with all names and store it in _senders;
    }

    public ServiceBusSender Resolve(ServiceBusQueue queue)
    {
        return _senders[queue];
    }
}
```

Then register this provider and use it in other clusses that you need to get different quees:

```
 _services.TryAddSingleton(implementationFactory => ServiceBusQueueProvider());
```

and in constructor:

```
public SomeClass(ServiceBusQueueProvider provider)
{
    _serviceBusSender  = provider.Resolve(ServiceBusQueue.ServiceBus1);
}
```

One more point is that you should change MessagingServiceConfiguration
This class is mapped to configuration. And in current implementation you can specify only one queue.
Change it like:

```
public class MessagingServiceConfiguration
{
    public List<MessagingServiceConfigurationItem> Queues { get; set; }
}

public class MessagingServiceConfigurationItem
{
    public string QueueName { get; set; }
    public string ListenAndSendConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

For anyone coming here in the future, I'd recommend using [ServiceBusClientBuilderExtensions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/src/Compatibility/ServiceBusClientBuilderExtensions.cs)

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddAzureClients(clientsBuilder =>
    {
        clientsBuilder.AddServiceBusClient("Client1ConnectionString")
          .WithName("Client1Name");
        clientsBuilder.AddServiceBusClient("Client2ConnectionString")
          .WithName("Client2Name");
    });
}
```

In order to retrieve it you must use `IAzureClientFactory<ServiceBusClient>` as below:

```
 public Constructor(IAzureClientFactory<ServiceBusClient> serviceBusClientFactory)
 {
     ServiceBusClient client1 = serviceBusClientFactory.CreateClient("Client1Name")
 }
```

Code snippets taken and simplified from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68688838/how-to-register-servicebusclient-for-dependency-injection) answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class as below with interface. Here is a very basic example.

Interface:

```
 public interface IAzureServiceBusConsumer
{
    Task Start();
    Task Stop();
}
```

Implimentation :

```
public class AzureServiceBusConsumer : IAzureServiceBusConsumer
{
    //Service Bus processor 
    private ServiceBusProcessor _userAddedProcessor;        
    private ServiceBusProcessor _userUpdatedProcessor;

    private readonly IUserReceivedService _userReceived;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;       


    private readonly string _serviceBusConnectionString;
    private readonly string _subscriptionUserAdded;
    private readonly string _subscriptionUserUpdated;
    private readonly string _UserAddedMessageTopic;
    

    public AzureServiceBusConsumer(IUserReceivedService userReceived ,IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _userReceived = userReceived;
        _configuration = configuration;          

        _serviceBusConnectionString = _configuration.GetValue<string>("ServiceBusConnectionString");
        _UserAddedMessageTopic = _configuration.GetValue<string>("UserAddedMessageTopic");
        _subscriptionUserAdded = _configuration.GetValue<string>("UserAddedSubscription");                 
       

        //Create a client to receive messages
        var client = new ServiceBusClient(_serviceBusConnectionString);

        //on client call you can provide different subscription
        _userAddedProcessor = client.CreateProcessor(_UserAddedMessageTopic, _subscriptionUserAdded);
        _userUpdatedProcessor = client.CreateProcessor(_UserAddedMessageTopic, _subscriptionUserUpdated);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// start the bus processor to look for any messages.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task Start()
    {           

        _userAddedProcessor.ProcessMessageAsync += OnUserAddedMessageReceived;
        _userAddedProcessor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;
        await _userAddedProcessor.StartProcessingAsync();
        _userUpdatedProcessor.ProcessMessageAsync += OnUserUpdatedMessageReceived;
        _userUpdatedProcessor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;
        await _userUpdatedProcessor.StartProcessingAsync();
       
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// stop the bus processor and dispose conn.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task Stop()
    {
        await _userAddedProcessor.StopProcessingAsync();
        await _userAddedProcessor.DisposeAsync();
        
    }
    Task ErrorHandler(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Exception.ToString());
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task OnUserAddedMessageReceived(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
    {
        var message = args.Message;
        var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);

        UserDto _UserRecivedDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDto>(body);

        //Save the recieved message then call CompleteMessageAsync
        await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
    }
```