# How to register ServiceBusClient for dependency injection?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, dependency-injection, servicebus

I’m trying to register `ServiceBusClient` from the new *Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus* package for dependency injection as recommended in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2) using `ServiceBusClientBuilderExtensions`, but I can’t find any documentation or any help online on how exactly to go about this.

I'm trying to add as below

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    ServiceBusClientBuilderExtensions.AddServiceBusClient(builder, Typsy.Domain.Configuration.Settings.Instance().Connections.ServiceBusPrimary);
}
```

but I'm getting the error

> The type 'Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IFunctionsHostBuilder' must be convertible to 'Azure.Core.Extensions.IAzureClientFactoryBuilder' in order to use it as parameter 'TBuilder' in the generic method 'IAzureClientBuilder<ServiceBusClient,ServiceBusClientOptions> Microsoft.Extensions.Azure.ServiceBusClientBuilderExtensions.AddServiceBusClient(this TBuilder, string)'

[image]

If anyone can help with this that'll be great!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[`ServiceBusClientBuilderExtensions.AddServiceBusClient`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/src/Compatibility/ServiceBusClientBuilderExtensions.cs#L18) is an extension method of `IAzureClientFactoryBuilder`:

```cs
public static IAzureClientBuilder<ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusClientOptions> AddServiceBusClient<TBuilder>(this TBuilder builder, string connectionString)
            where TBuilder : IAzureClientFactoryBuilder
```

To get an instance of `IAzureClientFactoryBuilder`, you need to call [`AzureClientServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAzureClients(IServiceCollection, Action<AzureClientFactoryBuilder>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.azure.azureclientservicecollectionextensions.addazureclients?view=azure-dotnet-preview) for a given `IServiceCollection`, which provides a delegate giving an instance of `IAzureClientFactoryBuilder`. (this method is in the [`Microsoft.Extensions.Azure`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Azure/) NuGet package)

To call that method, you can use the `IServiceCollection` provided by `IFunctionsHostBuilder`. With all of that, what you have should look something like:

```cs
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddAzureClients(clientsBuilder =>
    {
        clientsBuilder.AddServiceBusClient(Typsy.Domain.Configuration.Settings.Instance().Connections.ServiceBusPrimary)
          // (Optional) Provide name for instance to retrieve by with DI
          .WithName("Client1Name")
          // (Optional) Override ServiceBusClientOptions (e.g. change retry settings)
          .ConfigureOptions(options =>
          {
              options.RetryOptions.Delay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
              options.RetryOptions.MaxDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
              options.RetryOptions.MaxRetries = 3;
          });
    });
}
```

To retrieve the named instance, instead of using `ServiceBusClient` as the injected type you use `IAzureClientFactory<ServiceBusClient>`. **The `ServiceBusClient` is a Singleton regardless of whether you use a named instance or not.**

```cs
 public Constructor(IAzureClientFactory<ServiceBusClient> serviceBusClientFactory)
 {
     // Wherever you need the ServiceBusClient
     ServiceBusClient singletonClient1 = serviceBusClientFactory.CreateClient("Client1Name")
 }
```

Comment: How does this work with multiple namespaces or connection strings?

Comment: @devNull also do you know when registering ServiceBusClient as a dependency, is it registered as a singleton? If not do you have any idea on how I can register it as a singleton?

Comment: And would you know how I can pass in ServiceBusClientOptions when register ServiceBusClient as a dependency?

Comment: To access settings from the ConfigureService Method  you can use  var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings:ServiceConnectionStrings");  - see microsoft article about environment variables :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#environment-variables

Comment: @codea using the context could also be an option https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#customizing-configuration-sources

Comment: Will creating client in the function's constructor be a suggested approach? Because for every instance, we'll be creating new clients. We aren't reusing existing client. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: How to add the client with topic or queue name like in the past ? TopicClient(serviceBusSettings.ConnectionString, serviceBusSettings.TopicName, RetryPolicy.Default);

Comment: I am creating the sender instance at the function constructor public Processor(IAzureClientFactory<ServiceBusClient> serviceBusClientFactory)
        {
            _client = serviceBusClientFactory.CreateClient("TopicClientName");
            _sender = _client.CreateSender("topicname");
        }

Comment: @threeleggedrabbit if I'm not mistaken, that code recreates the sender on each request? the docs say that even the ServiceBusSender should be registered as a Singleton, but the Microsoft.Extensions.Azure DI extensions apparently do not support this?

Answer (score 13):

For those only in need of single servicebus client a simple singleton would suffice

**(Tested with .Net 6 Azure Functions v4):**

```
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(YourProjName.Startup))]

namespace YourProjName
{
 public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
 {
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
       
        var serviceBusConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusConnectionString");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceBusConnectionString))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Please specify a valid ServiceBusConnectionString in the Azure Functions Settings or your local.settings.json file.");
        }

        //using AMQP as transport
        builder.Services.AddSingleton((s) => {
            return new ServiceBusClient(serviceBusConnectionString, new ServiceBusClientOptions() { TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets }); 
        });

    }
 }
}
```

Then you could use it in the Azure Function constructor:

```
public Function1(ServiceBusClient client)
   {
       _client = client;
   }
```

Comment: this ist not good as the ServiceBusClient instance is not disposed correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Late to the party with this answer, but this article has some great examples including DI setup for the senders as well as the clients:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/messaging.servicebus-readme?view=azure-dotnet#registering-with-aspnet-core-dependency-injection

```
public async Task ConfigureServicesAsync(IServiceCollection services)
{
var adminClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient("<< SERVICE BUS CONNECTION STRING >>");
var queueNames = new List<string>();

await foreach (var queue in adminClient.GetQueuesAsync())
{
    queueNames.Add(queue.Name);
}

services.AddAzureClients(builder =>
{
    builder.AddServiceBusClient("<< SERVICE BUS CONNECTION STRING >>");

    foreach (var queueName in queueNames)
    {
        builder.AddClient<ServiceBusSender, ServiceBusClientOptions>((_, _, provider) =>
            provider
                .GetService<ServiceBusClient>()
                .CreateSender(queueName)
        )
        .WithName(queueName);
    }
});

}
```

Comment: the problem in doing it this way is that the queues and topics should exists from the beginning, otherwise you have to restart the services to load them.

Answer (score 3):

I was wondering the exact same thing, and while I like there is a specialized azure extension I did find another way I do prefer that seems less complicated and hopefully this can help others.

The code uses the **function delegate provided by .AddSingleton Method**. This function delegate will be called At the very end of the Build where you can make use of the service provider and retrieve your options (please correct me if I am wrong as documentation is dense and sparse at the same time :) ) .

Below is the key part:

```
serviceCollection.AddSingleton((serviceProvider) =>
{
    ServiceBusOptions options = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<ServiceBusOptions>>().Value;
    return new ServiceBusClient(options.ConnectionString);
});
```

**Full Code - speaks more :) **

```
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace ConsoleJson.Example
{
    class Startup
    {
        private static IHost DIHost;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IHostBuilder hostbuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(GetAppConfigurationDefinition);

            //Create Host (/build configuration)
            ConfigureSettings(hostbuilder);
            ConfigureServices(hostbuilder);

            DIHost = hostbuilder.Build();

            // Application code should start here.
            DIHost.Run();
        }


        static void GetAppConfigurationDefinition(HostBuilderContext ctx, IConfigurationBuilder config)
        {
            config.SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true) // for simplicity appsettings.production.json / appsettings.development.json are not there.  This is where settings would go.
           .Build();
        }

        public static void ConfigureServices(IHostBuilder hostbuilder)
        {
            hostbuilder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, serviceCollection) =>
            {

                serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ServiceBusClient>((serviceProvider) =>
                {
                    // options from appSettings.json
                    // leverages IOptions Pattern to get an options object from the DIHost Service provider
                    var myServiceBusOptions = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<ServiceBusOptions>>().Value;

                    var sbClientOptions=new ServiceBusClientOptions() { 
                        TransportType=ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpTcp,
                        RetryOptions=new ServiceBusRetryOptions() { Mode = ServiceBusRetryMode.Exponential }
                        // ...
                    };

                    // returns the ServiceBusClient Object configured per options we wanted
                    return new ServiceBusClient(myServiceBusOptions.ConnectionString, sbClientOptions);
                });

            });
        }

        public static void ConfigureSettings(IHostBuilder hostbuilder)
        {
            hostbuilder.ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, serviceCollection) =>
            {
                IConfiguration configurationRoot = hostBuilderContext.Configuration;
                serviceCollection.Configure<ServiceBusOptions>(configurationRoot.GetSection("ServiceBusOptions"));
            });
        }

        public class ServiceBusOptions
        {
            public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

**AppSettings.Json**

```
{
    "ServiceBusOptions": {
        "ConnectionString": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Newing up the ServiceBusClient in this way means the disposal will not be handled by the service container https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#services-not-created-by-the-service-container