# Replacing Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus with Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a message publisher that uses Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus and need to replace it with Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus as it is now deprecated.

Here is the code:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace gbx.infra.ware.Services
{
public interface IMessagePublisher
{
    public Task Publish<T>(T obj);
    public Task Publish(string raw);
    public Task<long> PublishScheduled<T>(T obj, DateTimeOffset time);

}
public class MessagePublisher : IMessagePublisher
{
    private readonly ITopicClient _topicClient;

    public MessagePublisher(ITopicClient topicClient)
    {
        _topicClient = topicClient;
    }

    public Task Publish<T>(T obj)
    {
        string objAsText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

        Message message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(objAsText));
        message.UserProperties["messageType"] = typeof(T).Name;
        return _topicClient.SendAsync(message);
    }

    public Task Publish(string raw)
    {
        Message message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(raw));
        message.UserProperties["messageType"] = "Raw";
        return _topicClient.SendAsync(message);
    }

    public Task<long> PublishScheduled<T>(T obj, DateTimeOffset time)
    {
        string objAsText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

        Message message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(objAsText));
        message.UserProperties["messageType"] = typeof(T).Name;
        return _topicClient.ScheduleMessageAsync(message, time);
    }
    }
    }
```

Is there a simple way i can make the change? I can't find any info on this.

The publisher is registered like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<ITopicClient>(x => new TopicClient(Configuration["ServiceBus:ConnectionString"], Configuration["ServiceBus:TopicName"]));
services.AddSingleton<IMessagePublisher, MessagePublisher>();
```

And injected into as needed.

What i want to do is to change the code in the Message Publisher only so that no changes need to be done in the code where it is used.

Comment: Have you already found the [migration guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/MigrationGuide.md#sending-messages)?

Comment: Yes, i have already looked at this. Unfortunately, i did not find i could work it out from the guide. I could not work out how i would inject the new publisher, how i would register it and how i would set the UserProperty. The original code was not mine, as i already mentioned i really want to make as few changes to the code as possible.

Comment: `UserProperties` is now `ApplicationProperties`. See `ServiceBusClient` type that allows creating [`ServiceBusSender`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusclient.createsender?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-servicebus-servicebusclient-createsender(system-string)). That's your new "ITopicClient".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would simply use the [migration guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/MigrationGuide.md#sending-messages) you would end up with

```cs
public interface IMessagePublisher
{
    public Task Publish<T>(T obj);
    public Task Publish(string raw);
    public Task<long> PublishScheduled<T>(T obj, DateTimeOffset time);

}

public class MessagePublisher : IMessagePublisher
{
    private readonly ServiceBusSender _serviceBusSender;

    public MessagePublisher(ServiceBusSender serviceBusSender)
    {
        _serviceBusSender = serviceBusSender;
    }

    public Task Publish<T>(T obj)
    {
        string objAsText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

        ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(objAsText));
        message.ApplicationProperties["messageType"] = typeof(T).Name;
        return _serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(message);
    }

    public Task Publish(string raw)
    {
        ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(raw));
        message.ApplicationProperties["messageType"] = "Raw";
        return _serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(message);
    }

    public Task<long> PublishScheduled<T>(T obj, DateTimeOffset time)
    {
        string objAsText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

        ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(objAsText));
        message.ApplicationProperties["messageType"] = typeof(T).Name;
        return _serviceBusSender.ScheduleMessageAsync(message, time);
    }
}
```

To register the `MessagePublisher` try:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IMessagePublisher>(p => 
        new MessagePublisher(
        new ServiceBusClient(Configuration["ServiceBus:ConnectionString"]).CreateSender(Configuration["ServiceBus:TopicName"])));
```

Note: there are other ways to register the message publisher, see [How to register ServiceBusClient for dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68688838/how-to-register-servicebusclient-for-dependency-injection). You might need some minor modifications of `MessagePublisher` though.