# How to listen to the serialized Azure Message Bus message in c#?

Tags: c#, azure, microservices, message-bus

I am using the Azure Message Bus to communicate with my microservices. I am able to send the message under the topic Account Updated from service A. However, the message is not being read by another service called B. I mean if I send "Hello" string, it is being read properly. But the serialized message is not being decoded at the listener.

Here is the message that is sent from service A:

```
var invoiceMessage = new InvoiceMessageDto<AccountInvoicingMessageDto>
                {
                    MessageType = MessageType.Create,
                    InvoiceType = InvoiceType.Account,
                    CreationDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                    MessageDto = new AccountInvoicingMessageDto
                    {
                        AccountId = request.Id,
                        OrganizationName = request.OrganizationName,
                        AccountStatus = AccountStatusEnum.ApprovedPendingPayment,
                        FlatFee = flatfee
                    }
                };
                
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Success Success when sending Account Message");
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Success when sending Account Update Message");
                    _azServiceBusConsumer.SendMessage(invoiceMessage, MessageTopics.ACCOUNT_UPDATED);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Error when sending Message: {ex}");
                }
```

The `_azServiceBusConsumer` is an instance of the interface `IAzServiceBusConsumer` as shown below:

[image]

```
namespace Services.Common.Interface
{
    public interface IAzServiceBusConsumer
    {

        void Start();
        void Stop();

        void SendMessage(IntegrationBaseMessage message, string? topicName);

    }
}
```

And here is how I am listening to it in service B:

_receiverClient is defined as:

```
 _receiverClient = new SubscriptionClient(_config["MessageBus:ConnectionString"],
                                                     MessageTopics.ACCOUNT_UPDATED,
                                                     _config["MessageBus:SubscriptionName"],
                                                     ReceiveMode.PeekLock,
                                                     RetryPolicy.Default);
```

And then it is used by the listener as:

```
_receiverClient.RegisterMessageHandler(async (message, cancelToken) =>
            {
                var bodyBytes = message.Body;
                var ourMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bodyBytes);

                _logger.LogInformation($"Received: {ourMessage}");
}
```

When checked in the debug mode, the `message` variable shows the message that is received but `bodyBytes` shows nothing when the mouse is hovered there.

So, how should I decode the message received by my listener (service B)?

Any help would be more than appreciable.

Comment: What is the type of `_azServiceBusConsumer`? What's the SDK you are using?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code for both `IAzServiceBusConsumer` and its concrete implementation.

Comment: @GauravMantri Added more info to my question. Thank you.

Comment: They also asked for the concrete implementation... doesn't matter though, it looks like you're using the [deprecated SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73359526/replacing-microsoft-azure-servicebus-with-azure-messaging-servicebus), try using `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` instead as it is more intuitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RegisterMessageHandler method of queue is used to register the function that will process the message.
This method expects two parameters: handler and message handler option.
something like :

```
// Configure the MessageHandler Options in terms of exception handling, number of concurrent messages to deliver etc.  
    var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)  
    {  
        MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,  
        AutoComplete = false  
    };  
  
    // Register the function that will process messages 

    queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken), messageHandlerOptions);
```

and after that your   queueClient ready for call   CloseAsync() liek

```
  queueClient.CloseAsync().Wait();
```

and your sender should be something like

```
  var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));  
 await queueClient.SendAsync(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

from the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messages-payloads):

> Payload serialization When in transit or stored inside of Service Bus,
> the payload is always an opaque, binary block. The ContentType
> property enables applications to describe the payload, with the
> suggested format for the property values being a MIME content-type
> description according to IETF RFC2045; for example,
> application/json;charset=utf-8.
>
> ,,,
>
> If the payload of a message can't be deserialized, then it's
> recommended to dead-letter the message.

Try to serialize the message using JSON format before sending it to the queue/topic:

```
            var messageBody = JsonSerializer.Serialize(invoiceMessage );
            //Set content type and Guid
            var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody)) {
                MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    ContentType = "application/json"
            };
            await client.SendAsync(message);
```