# Trying to register Azure ServiceBus Clients in .NET 6 Azure Function v4 program.cs

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0, azureservicebus

I have a new .NET 6 project for an Azure Function v4 application.

I have multiple service buses each with multiple queues and topics, I'm trying to inject `ServiceBusClients` into the app with `Microsoft.Extensions.Azure`.

I'm trying to follow [Inject multiple ServiceBusClient in ASP.net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970273/inject-multiple-servicebusclient-in-asp-net-core) and this https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/.

However, I'm using the new guidance of using a `program.cs` file instead of a `startup.cs` file.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var localRoot = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsScriptRoot");
var azureRoot = $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Home")}/site/wwwroot";
var actualRoot = localRoot ?? azureRoot;

var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();

string connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("MyDBConnectionString")!;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
    {
        config
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>(
            options => SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(options, connectionString)
        );

        services.AddHttpClient();
        services.RegisterServicesLayer();

        string crmConnectionString = config.GetConnectionString("crm.pub")!;
        services.AddAzureClients(clientsBuilder =>
        {
            clientsBuilder.AddServiceBusClient(crmConnectionString).WithName("CrmPublish");
        });
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

I'm getting this error:

> Error CS1061
> 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddAzureClients' and no accessible extension method 'AddAzureClients' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

All the libraries are installed.

Any suggestions?